# I would like to change the submit color in Pardot when the cursor hovers over the button

Tags: html, css, pardot

I am trying to change the color of the form's submit button when the cursor hovers over the button but I am not sure why the code isn't working.

I have tried different versions of the code including:

form.form p.submit input a:hover {
    background-color:E8E8E8;

and  form.form p.submit input:hover {
     background-color:E8E8E8;

```
<style type="text/css"> 
form.form input.text, form.form textarea.standard, form.form select, form.form input.date { 
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
   border:solid 1px #00BCF1;
   font-size:16px;
   color:#000000;
   width:550px;
   -moz-border-radius:px;
   -webkit-border-radius:px;
   border-radius:15px;
   padding-top:5px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
   padding-left:5px;
   padding-right:5px;
}
form.form p label {
   font-size:14px;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   font-weight:normal;
   padding-top:15px;
   padding-bottom:5px;
}
form.form p.submit input {
   background-color:#B2D235;
   border:solid 1px #00BCF1;
   font-size:16px;
   color:#003c71;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding-top:15px;
   padding-bottom:15px;
   padding-right:25px;
   padding-left:25px;
   -moz-border-radius:0px;
   -webkit-border-radius:0px;
   border-radius:30px;

}

form.form p.submit input a:hover {
    background-color:E8E8E8;
}
form.form p.submit {
   margin-top:40px;
   margin-bottom:0px;
   text-align:left;
}
form.form p.required label, form.form span.required label {
    background:none !important; 
    font-weight:bold;
}
form.form p.required label.field-label:after {
    content:"*"; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}

 </style>
```

I would like to have the button change color but I can't seem to make that happen.

Comment: I see your color is incorrect a:hover. You need to include the #

Answer (score 2):

One thing i immediately notice is that you didnt put a "#" in front of the hex code.
So it should look something like this instead

```
form.form p.submit input a:hover {
    background-color:#E8E8E8
}
```

Aside from that, seeing your associated HTML could help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.btn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the Way you are missing **#** before the color code **color:#E8E8E8**

> form.form p.submit input a:hover { background-color:E8E8E8;

You can find the answer on the link: [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp](http://button%20styles)